# Java GUI syntax error in SQL statment

Tags: java, sql, syntax

```
itemID STRING   
purchesPrice DOUBLE   
quantity DOUBLE   
vendor STRING   
unitM  STRING   

jcombo1=CB_vendor.getSelectedItem().toString();  
jcombo2=CB_unit.getSelectedItem().toString();      

conn=ShopDb.database();

Sql_insert="insert into table itemmanag(itemID,purchesPrice,sellPrice,quantity,vendor,unitM)
values
( "+txt_itemID.getText()+"','"+Item_Pprice.getText()+"','"+txt_itemSprice.getText()
   +"','"+txt_qunti.getText()+"','" +jcombo1+"','"+jcombo2+ " ')";
```

**ERROR:**

> you have an error in your sql syntax ; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL SERVER
>          version for the right syntanx to use near"table itemmanage(itemID,purchesPrice,quantity,vendor, 
>          unitM)values(DA atline 1

Comment: At the first attribute is a single quote missing: `values( "+`. But try to use prepaered statement.

Comment: im getting error when i try to save data

Comment: @DanRox, We mean, show us the error.

Comment: im getting error when i try to save data it say **YOU HAVE AN ERROE IN SQLSYNTAX CHECK THE MANUAL THAT CORRESPONDS TO YOUR SQL SERVER VERSION **

Comment: @DanRox, Don't make our life harder, we came to help you. Please edit you **main post** to include the **FULL** error message.

Comment: SORRY @OrelEraki DOINg it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god, thanks @Orel Eraki, of course beside the unbalanced single-quotes you will have to follow proper SQL Insert Syntax and hava a form of 'INSERT INTO ...', try it like this (see my change dirctly after "values(" as the one of Orel Eraki (no 'table' "keyword" after into):

```
Sql_insert="insert into itemmanag(itemID,purchesPrice,sellPrice,quantity,vendor,unitM )values('"+txt_itemID.getText()+"','"+Item_Pprice.getText()+"','"+txt_itemSprice.getText()+"','"+txt_qunti.getText()+"','" +jcombo1+"','"+jcombo2+ "')";
```

Comment: same problem i fixed every thingi you guys  told still same problem

Comment: See my update, Orel Eraki in the comments of the above answer provided the second correction.

Comment: When it comes to such exceptions i recomend you have a String like SQL_insert printed out (System.out.println or something) so you can copy and paste it to a Tool like SQL Developper, Toad, Squirrel or whatever to better see such issues.

Comment: When it comes to SQL itself, dont worry i am a SWE for 10 years now and still quickly check google with questions like '<Database Type> insert into"

Comment: THNX IT'S FIXED AND NOW WORK FINE

Comment: @OrelEraki Yeah sorry my English is not that good :( 
I meant to honor your above comment, i have stared at the statement like half a minute to see the unbalanced quotes but have overseen the 'table' word there.  (Thats also why i upvotet your answer;))

Answer (score 2):

As `Jens` said, you have a missing single quote at the beginning of the values.

Change this:

```
values( "+txt_itemID.getText()
```

With this:

```
values('" + txt_itemID.getText()
```

Also: Remove the keyword `table` from the query.

**Furthermore**, you should highly consider changing you sql building to use [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in order to have much cleaner code and more important avoid [SQL-Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

If you still persist of using this query instead of [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) it will be best if you will make you query much more readable.

**Example:**

```
String valuesFormatted = String.format(
    "('%s', %d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
    , txt_itemID.getText()
    , Double.parseDouble(Item_Pprice.getText())
    , txt_itemSprice.getText()
    , txt_qunti.getText()
    , jcombo1
    , jcombo2)";

Sql_insert = "
    insert into itemmanag
    (itemID,purchesPrice,sellPrice,quantity,vendor,unitM )
    values " + valuesFormatted;
```

**Note:** Code hasn't been tested.

Comment: @Dan, Also remove table from the query.